# Update the model and selected option of a select that is generated using ng-options

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

Unfortunately I'm just going round in circle trying to work this out - any help would be really appreciated.

I would like to update the model and selected option of a select that is generated using ng-options.

Here are the values for the options:

```
var blahOptionValues = [
  {valueForModel: '1', optionText: 'a'},
  {valueForModel: '2', optionText: 'b'},
  {valueForModel: '3', optionText: 'c'},
]
```

Here is my view:

```
<select ng-model="blahModel" ng-options="item.valueForModel as item.optionText for item in blahOptionValues"></select>
```

As a result of another event, how would I update the "blahModel" with the relevant value? Would this also update the selected value in the view as well?

Comment: Your select should be updated. If it does not, you may be changing another bladModel in a different scope. You should also include the code for 'another event' that changes blahModel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Sander_P - there is no scope conflict going on - I think the event is superfluous to my example as it is just a method that is called from the view that gets hit without any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will update the view as well.
Please check the demo in plunker: link: http://plnkr.co/edit/7XVrn7GmfKrJS7e4fvuH?p=preview`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.blahOptionValues = [
      {valueForModel: '1', optionText: 'a'},
      {valueForModel: '2', optionText: 'b'},
      {valueForModel: '3', optionText: 'c'},
    ];
    
  $scope.blahModel = '2';  
  
  $scope.update = function(){
    
    $scope.blahModel = '1';
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">{{blahModel}}
    <select ng-model="blahModel" ng-options="item.valueForModel as item.optionText for item in blahOptionValues"></select>
    <button ng-click="update()" >update</button>
  </div>
```

`

Comment: Thanks @Vidyadhar - I'm sure this was one of the first things I tried, and then started going round in circles when it wasn't working - anyway, it's working now, many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the same reference in order to show a value in the select.

That is, if you wish to set the blahModel based on an event, you need to do the following:

```
//Assume that the following code is in your event handler.
//Assuming here that you want to set the value  of the select to 'b'
$scope.blahModel = $scope.blahOptionValues[1].valueForModel
```

If you directly set the value to `2` it will not work since it is not the same reference. You need to explicitly use the same iterator as the one used in `ng-repeat`. Also, there seems to be a bug in your code - blahOptionValues should be on the scope and not as a local variable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @callmekatootie. The model is now being updated, but the select itself does not get updated - I tried wrapping it in a `$scope.$apply`, but that didn't work. I'm actually using the 'controller as' syntax instead of using $scope - I didn't include this in my example but it's in my real code.

Comment: `select does not get updated` - what does that mean? If the model is updated, it should get reflected in the view right?

Comment: the select element in the view - you'd have thought so, but it doesn't.

Comment: Try using an object instead of a variable then - `myObject.blahModel`

Comment: Then you are doing something else wrong which you have not described. If you see the documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) you can see that the above solution works just like the example shown in the documentation at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

With reference from "As a result of another event, how would I update the "blahModel" with the relevant value"

I am extending your code. I have one textbox in which you will enter values either 1,2 or 3 and click in set button and select value is updated.

I have added *track by* in ng-options.

Html :-

```
<select ng-model="blahModel" ng-options="item.valueForModel as item.optionText for item in blahOptionValues track by item.valueForModel"></select>
<input type="text" data-ng-model="searchSelect"/>
<input type="button" data-ng-click="SetSelect()" value="Set"/>
```

Angular Code :-

```
$scope.SetSelect = function () { 
    $scope.blahModel={valueForModel:$scope.searchSelect};;
};
```

Comment: Jay if its working for you.. you can always upvote  :)